# String replacing in a data frame based on another data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace, str-replace

## The problem

I am a scholar who needs to anonymise a large data frame of tweets to keep on my research. In this data frame, there are over 279280 rows each containing the original tweet text columns with a variety of metadata.

Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(text = c("@Rod comentem aqui utilizando  #BrequeDosApps #AmanhaTemBrequedosApps  \nNão pode ser só as tags sozinhas pq vira spam!!", 
"@Roderick #BrequeDosApps ✊", "@Rodson E ai pessoal vamos levantar a hastag #BrequeDosApps"
), screen_names = c("@Rod", "@Roderick", "@Rodson")), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(text = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), screen_names = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x7f9cd0ae72e0>, row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I created a data frame with two columns: 1) all tweet handles "@username" 2) all the substitution for anonymisation. I have to substitute all handles from the text itself and from the screen_name column. Here is the sample of my substitution table:

```
structure(list(screen_names = c("@Rod", "@Roderick", "@Rodson"
), new_names = c("@7cdb6a2e", "@766b33e3", "@1c90c952")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## Solution (Not working)

I tried `stri_replace_all_fixed`. The actual commands were

```
sample_tweets2$screen_names <- stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(str = sample_tweets2$screen_names, pattern = df.substitute$screen_names,replacement = df.substitute$new_names, vectorize_all = FALSE)

sample_tweets2$text <- stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(str = sample_tweets2$text, pattern = df.substitute$screen_names,replacement = df.substitute$new_names, vectorize_all = FALSE)
```

The problem is: it replaces all the handles with `@Rod*` using it as a `regex` pattern, not an exact on the letter mach, so a handle line @Roderick ends up as **@7cdb6a2eerick** and not as **@766b33e3** as in my original substitution table. Here is an example:

```
structure(list(text = c("@Rod comentem aqui utilizando  #BrequeDosApps #AmanhaTemBrequedosApps  \nNão pode ser só as tags sozinhas pq vira spam!!", 
"@Roderick #BrequeDosApps ✊", "@Rodson E ai pessoal vamos levantar a hastag #BrequeDosApps"
), screen_names = c("@7cdb6a2e", "@7cdb6a2eerick", "@7cdb6a2eson"
)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(text = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), screen_names = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x7f9cd0ae72e0>, row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Some complications:

1. Sometimes the same handle has more than one tweet, so being many times present in the *screen_name* column.
2. It is absolutely necessary to keep the *text* column, because that is the main source for linguistic analysis.
3. The handles should be kept in the text anonimysed

Please, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you use `merge(sampletweets2, df.substitute, by = "screen_names")` to combine your two tables, then drop fields you don't want from the result?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I works fine for the *screen_name* column, but how should I procedure for the *text* column?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `gsub()` to remove all words that begin with `@`? e.g. `gsub("@\\w+ *", "", sampletweets2$text)`

Comment: That is a very nice idea, but The handles should be kept in the text anonimysed for the analysis.

Comment: Hi @RodLL, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNames`and `str_replace_all` in this way:

```
subs <- setNames(df2$new_names, df2$screen_names)
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(df1$screen_names, subs)
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(text = c("@Rod comentem aqui utilizando  #BrequeDosApps #AmanhaTemBrequedosApps  \nNão pode ser só as tags sozinhas pq vira spam!!", 
                        "@Roderick #BrequeDosApps ✊", "@Rodson E ai pessoal vamos levantar a hastag #BrequeDosApps"
), screen_names = c("@Rod", "@Roderick", "@Rodson")), spec = structure(list(
  cols = list(text = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                 "collector")), screen_names = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                           "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                 "collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df2 <-   structure(list(screen_names = c("@Rod", "@Roderick", "@Rodson"
  ), new_names = c("@7cdb6a2e", "@766b33e3", "@1c90c952")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                          -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This replaces all sensitive information from `screen_names` and `text` with your anonymized names:

```
df2 <- merge(df, lookup, by = "screen_names")
df2$text2 <- gsub("@\\w+ *", "df2$new_names",  df2$text)

# Drop sensitive information
df3 <- df2[,setdiff(names(df2), c("screen_names", "text")]
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  screen_names = c("@Rod", "@Roderick", "@Rodson"),
  text = c("@Rod comentem aqui utilizando  #BrequeDosApps #AmanhaTemBrequedosApps  \nNão pode ser só as tags sozinhas pq vira spam!!", "@Roderick #BrequeDosApps", "@Rodson E ai pessoal vamos levantar a hastag #BrequeDosApps"))

lookup <- data.frame(
  screen_names = c("@Rod", "@Roderick", "@Rodson"),
  new_names = c("@7cdb6a2e", "@766b33e3", "@1c90c952"))
```